# Converting Intern to full time, but can't be in the same team I wanted to be

Tags: interviewing, management, job-change, internship, job-offer

I am a C++ guy and a right out of college (Masters, graduating DEC 2012). I gave my interview for a storage Domain Company, last April and coded close to 2000 lines in C++, as a part of interview process for the UNIX team and got the offer.

When I joined they asked me to code a test tool (that can be used by internal testers) in BASH/PYTHON, I chose Python, but made it Object oriented to be used in all Unix platforms. The manager was happy with the progress, he never gave any negative reviews all through the process. Just three weeks before the end of internship, I showed my demo of the project for all the managers of the company at status meeting. While doing that our senior director was impressed and asked my manager, if it is possible to merge it in next immediate release. So I guess, I did a okay job.

I spoke to my manager about potential full time that afternoon and said my earliest available date is right after the internship, since I am course complete, even though my graduation is on December. He was like, I need to check. He called me after 15 minutes and said, we need to do an interview. I agreed and gave an interview immediately with the week. There was a debugging test, where I cleared 4 out of 5 (logical) errors and gave an interview. I would rate the interview from okay - good, because even though I never gave him the right answer straight away, I derived and gave him the right answers for most questions.

The next day my manager said, your C/C++ skills are good but we are looking for people with Unix experience of 4-5 years (which is true, checked the insider portal), I will map you to some other managers, don't worry, I will definitely find you some thing.

Now I have to talk to the manager of BUILD team of the product. I am not so much interested in that position, I am not quite sure, what I need to do.

Do I need to:

- Reject the offer out right? I have still 4 months to graduate and 3 months OPT period, I am from India.
- Or take that and go to a different job when I graduate?
- or ask him to find a different team(with more development work)?

Please suggest, in fact let me know, if I have made any mistakes in the way I handled so far....

Comment: Why so much needless information? Like, "I coded close to 2000 lines in C++ to get the internship offer" - why do we need to know this, and who on earth gets you to program 2000 lines for an interview anyway? Did you stay all day or something? It really sounds like you're bragging.

Comment: Lol. I was nervous at that time. I just wanted to pick the right option. It's been 2 years since I asked the question anyway. Thanks for finding it back.

Comment: So what are you currently doing?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine His question had nothing to do with "bragging". C++ and 2000 lines is a very significant aspect in programming and with regards to his question.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, you are not a "C++ guy"; you are a developer.  You will work with many different languages over your career.  If you work on the build team, you will learn how builds work.  Which doesn't sound like something you know much about now.  It will likely exposes you to different teams and you'll learn more about the industry.

Ask the build manager what you will be doing.  In some places the build team just does support.  In other companies (like mine), it is a very interesting job with real development work.  Writing plugins, etc.

Plus, it is likely you will gain UNIX knowledge and experience while on the build team which will help you fill a gap.  UNIX is a useful skill regardless of what other languages you are using.

Comment: Agreed, I agree with what you said. I will speak to the Build Manager tomorrow and will post it here. One more thing, I also heard that there is an opening in the another team(SAN/NAS) in my company. Is there a way that I can talk to my manager with out inviting any troubles? Once these two are done, I will post what the Manager's say and it would be really great, if you could give me more advice with better picture.... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3):

> your C/C++ skills are good but we are looking for people with Unix experience of 4-5 years (which is true, checked the insider portal),

I don't like that message, and scarcely believe it.

Take the job if you need it.  If you really want to program, keep looking.  If you can write C++, you can quickly learn enough about Unix to be useful.  It's great to get experienced people, but most are thrilled to just find anyone competent.

Comment: No, if they ask me to work for the Unix team, I would be more than happy. But they said, the need people with Unix experience in additional to c++. So they are planning to switch me to, build team and I am not exactly sure about the job description(will talk to the build manager on Monday). But I am pretty sure I will be coding in scripting, not c++. So I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of another job offer, I would accept this job. You have apparently impressed them already, and that bodes well for your career.

If you still want a C++ job, look for one. If find one, you can choose. In my opinion, a "build" job where the people already know you and like your work is better than the "C++" job which you want, but where nobody knows your skill.